# What does the ?= operator do in Swift?

Tags: swift, operators

I just came across some code that looks like this:

```
var msg:String = "";
msg ?= err["ErrorMessage"].text;
```

The *err* variable is from SwiftyXMLParser from what I can see in the code. I'm at a loss about the meaning of the ?= (questionmark-equals) operator. I cannot find documentation about it. What is it doing?

Comment: There is no such operator in the Swift language or standard library. It is probably defined in one of your frameworks.

Comment: And there is it: https://github.com/yahoojapan/SwiftyXMLParser/blob/master/SwiftyXMLParser/XML.swift#L37 ...

Comment: The documentation conspired against me. C++ and C# don't have arbitrary operator definition and the Apple documentation mentioned standard operator overloading before mentioning custom operators. I stopped reading too soon because I had to write code without time to find the page of documentation that would reveal the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is a quite interesting topic in Swift language.

In other programming languages, it is closed to operator overloading whereas in Swifty terms, it is called **Custom Operators**. Swift has his own standard operator, but we can add additional operator too. Swift has 4 types of operators, among them, first 3 are available to use with custom operators:

- **Infix**: Used between two values, like the addition operator (e.g. 1 + 2)
- **Prefix**: Added before a value, like the negative operator (e.g. -3).
- **Postfix**: Added after a value, like the force-unwrap operator (e.g. objectNil!)
- Ternary: Two symbols inserted between three values.

Custom operators can begin with one of the ASCII characters /, =, -, +, !, *, %, <, >, &, |, ^, ?, or ~, or one of the Unicode characters.

New operators are declared at a global level using the operator keyword, and are marked with the prefix, infix or postfix modifiers:

Here is a sample example in the playground[**Swift 4**].

```
 infix operator ?=

 func ?= (base: inout String, with: String)
  {
     base = base + " " + with
  }

  var str = "Stack"
  str ?= "Overflow"
  print(str)
```

Output:

```
Stack Overflow
```

Please check the topic name [Advanced operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID28) in apple doc.